# Phonegap IOS App with local storage

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I need to develop an app for iOS with some basic functionality and since I'm not experienced with Objective C but with Web development, I need to know if it's possible to do it using  Phonegap.

This app will be like a book with chapters that needs to be updated on a daily basis.
There'll be a CMS in a server where the content will be updated. Text and pictures.

The app will be running on iPhone and iPad that sometimes may not be connected to the network. When connected they need to check for updates and save in a local database to be available when off-line.

Is this possible using Phonegap?

Is there any local database in iOS like SQLite? Or do I need to store everything in files? 
Can we save the text in a database and the pictures somewhere in a folder? Or everything needs to be saved in the local database?

What are the best plugins, features, methods that I'll need to look into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both LocalStorage and WebSQL in a PhoneGap app. LocalStorage is just... localStorage. Check the MDN docs for it. Ditto for WebSQL.